# Ckeditor with image drag and drop /image insert in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

I need a **WYSIWYG Editor** with feature to drag and drop image or the image can be uploaded and inserted in the editor.I tried with **ckeditor** in laravel 5.2 .
This is my code for image upload URL

```
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = "{{route('infos.upload',['_token' => csrf_token() ])}}";
```

In console it shows

```
http://localhost/laravel/public/%7B%7Broute('infos.upload',['_token'%20=%3E%20csrf_token()%20])%7D%7D?CKEditor=question&CKEditorFuncNum=2&langCode=en
```

And i am getting error access forbidded.

If possible please provide complete tutorial for integrating **ckeditor** with image upload in laravel.

Comment: Where do you write `route('infos.upload'...`? in php file?

Comment: i wrote this in config.js

Comment: You should write it in php file